# TypeError: integer argument expected, got float in python3.9

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am new python user,I try to make a color picker in python, but I get this error.

```
File "/Users/hayashi/Desktop/Pythonfolder/picker.py", line 11, in checkColor
    im = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=bbox)
  File "/Users/hayashi/Desktop/Pythonfolder/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PIL/ImageGrab.py", line 41, in grab
    im_resized = im.resize((right - left, bottom - top))
TypeError: integer argument expected, got float
```

This might be because the parameters `size` or `box` contain float values instead of integers.

but how can i fix it?

```
from pynput import keyboard
from pynput import mouse
from PIL import Image, ImageGrab

def getHex(rgb):
    return '%02X%02X%02X'%rgb


def checkColor(x,y):
    bbox = (x,y,x+1,y+1)
    im = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=bbox)
    rgbim = im.convert('RGB')
    r,g,b = rgbim.getpixel((0,0))
    print(f'COLOR: rgb{(r,g,b)} | HEX #{getHex((r,g,b))}')
    
   
def onClick(x,y, button, pressed):
    if pressed and button == mouse.Button.left:
        checkColor(x,y)

def onRel(key):
    if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
        mlstnr.stop()
        return False



if __name__ == '__main__':
    with keyboard.Listener(on_release = onRel) as klstnr:
        with mouse.Listener(on_click = onClick) as mlstnr:
            klstnr.join()
            mlstnr.join()
```

Comment: Try converting`x` and `y` arguments to integers before passing it to `checkBox`. `checkBox(int(x), int(y))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shoulde convert the X,Y To Int,in this line of code.

```
bbox = (int(x),int(y),int(x)+1,int(y)+1)
```